# List all layer 3 protocols available in my system?

Tags: networking

I am studying the OSI model and I have some doubts.

- How do I list layer 3 (OSI) protocols available/running in my system?
- Can I monitor them?
- Can I access to them (other than IP) from an programming interface or
  a socket?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried netstat?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with netstat but i could not get to see some protocols like ICMP that are running (i.e. I do ping and it works but netstat dont show), the closest thing I got to display ICMP is using `netstat -s`. If nestat is the right tool answer the question and will accept it.

Comment: Maybe wait first to see if someone has a better idea.